# Laravel 5.5 can't get record from DB

Tags: database, laravel

I try to learn Laravel 5.5, but I have problem to use DB;
DB Table have records.
Following code return some records.

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from todays where FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d') = '2019/03/04'"));
```

But following code doesn't return any records. What is wrong this ?

```
$result = DB::table('todays')->where(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d')", DB::raw('2019/03/04')))->get();
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: `todays.login` maybe the table isn't referenced as `todays`?

Comment: todays.login or login  got same result.

Comment: what does `toSql()` return replacing the `get()` method?

Comment: resurt for toSql() is  "select * from `todays` where FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d') is null" - DB::raw('2019/03/04') => is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be wrong.

```
$result = DB::table('todays')->where(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d')"), DB::raw('2019/03/04'))->get();
```

or

```
$result = DB::table('todays')->where(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d')"), '2019/03/04')->get();
```

First one is more of an error-prone while the second one is used as pdo statement.

Comment: `DB::table('table_name')->where(DB::raw('whatever_field'), 'operator_optional', 'value')`, you didn't provide the value in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I got answer. It might
$result = DB::table('todays')
                ->where(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(login, '%Y/%m/%d')"),  DB::raw("'2019/03/04'"))
                ->get();

Comment: if you don't put the `operator`, it's `=` by default. you can omit that.